# Conditionally update the temporary table while assign new value to a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case, variable-assignment

I am trying to update (or create) a column in a temporary table by assigning a variable and update that variable conditionally as well in SQL Server Management Studio.

I wrote the the following code but got an syntax error:

```
DECLARE @VARI INT = 0;

UPDATE #test1_b
SET Test_group = @VARI, 
    @VARI = CASE 
                WHEN TARGET_WEB = PREVIOUS 
                    THEN @VARI
                    ELSE @VARI + 1 
            END;
```

Here is the error I got:

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> Parse error at line: 3, column: 7: Incorrect syntax near '('.

I am very confused as I don't even include any '(' in my code. I was trying to follow this instruction: [Inline Variable Assignment in UPDATE Statement](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/06/29/inline-variable-assignment-in-update/). Below is the first few line and my expected outcome of my table:

| Test_group | TARGET_WEB | PREVIOUS | time | Expected group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | web 1 | Na | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | web 2 | web 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | web 2 | web 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | web 1 | web 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | web 3 | web 1 | 5 | 3 |

Ultimately I am trying to group by the rows with consecutive webs values and sum up the total time that user stay at each web before they leave the page. Here is the desired outcome after aggregation:

| Expected Group | TARGET_WEB | total time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | web 1 | 1 |
| 2 | web 2 | 5 |
| 3 | web 1 | 4 |
| 4 | web 3 | 5 |

I don't know if SQL allows people update the variables using variable itself in the `UPDATE` statement or not. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used that approach with SQL Server, but the code you posted works fine, so the syntax error must be caused by something else in the code. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb086686959324d6b157ae8fd6283b5e That said, could you post a bit more sample data and an example of the expected results? Because there may be other ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: I'd be much more inclined to use windowed functions rather than the "quirky update", e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e83c4f295b283e10333a3151d52a07e7 Although as SOS says, a bit more of an explanation about what you are trying to achieve and more than a couple of rows of sample data and expected results would also help.

Comment: Hey guys. Thank you for the suggestions. I just edited the post. My ultimate goal is to group by the consecutive rows and do some aggregations. I was trying to create a column to show the consecutive relation between the rows so that I can group by them later.

Answer (score 0):

It seems You are trying to update field test_n with variable @vari and at the same time updating value of variable @vari. I suggest to update field instead of variable. Refer below code.

```
DECLARE @VARI INT = 0;

UPDATE #test1_b
SET test_n = CASE 
                WHEN TARGET_NUM = PREVIOUS 
                    THEN @VARI
                ELSE @VARI + 1 
             END;
```

Comment: Yeah the only problem with your solution is that the variable @VARI is not updated, which leaves me only 2 distinct value (0 and 1). The ultimate goal is to create a column that identify the consecutive rows with the same values so that I can group by later.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you what you want based on your sampled data and expected results:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T (Test_group INT, TARGET_WEB VARCHAR(5), PREVIOUS VARCHAR(5), time INT, ExpectedGroup INT);

INSERT INTO #T(Test_group, TARGET_WEB, PREVIOUS, time, ExpectedGroup)
VALUES
    (1, 'web 1', 'Na', 1, 1),
    (1, 'web 2', 'web 1', 2, 2),
    (1, 'web 2', 'web 2', 3, 2),
    (1, 'web 1', 'web 2', 4, 3),
    (1, 'web 3', 'web 1', 5, 3);


SELECT  t.NewExpectedGroup,
        t.TARGET_WEB,
        SUM(t.time)
FROM    (   SELECT  Test_group, 
                    TARGET_WEB, 
                    PREVIOUS, 
                    time, 
                    ExpectedGroup,
                    NewExpectedGroup = SUM(CASE WHEN TARGET_WEB = [PREVIOUS] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY [time])
            FROM    #T
        ) AS t
GROUP BY t.NewExpectedGroup, t.TARGET_WEB
ORDER BY t.NewExpectedGroup;
```

It works simply using a conditional windowed function, adding 1 to the sum only if `TARGET_WEB <> PREVIOUS`. The main thing to note here though, is that this requires some kind of order within the windowed function. In your example it works because `time` happens to be incremental, but in your actual scenario I'd guess this is very unlikely to be the case, and you'll need to use another column (presumably some kind of created time) to specify the order in which to apply your expected grouping.